How do you get the author of a comment in an excel spreadsheet using epplus?
If an author with the name "John Smith" comments on a cell in an excel spreadsheet, I am not able to get back "John Smith". Instead what I get back, using epplus, is a guid that has this format:
tc={xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
here is some sample code for context:
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(pathToExcelFile))){
    var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheet[0];
    var cell = worksheet.Cells[0,0]; // comment made by John Smith is on this cell
    var result = cell.Comment.Author; // result is tc={12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123}
}

Not sure why epplus is not able to get the actual author name. Also, I tried using the guid assuming it was the correct guid within active directory:
UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain), IdentityType.Guid, guid) 

but that did not work either. How can I get the name of a commenter on a cell?

Try downloading the OpenXML Productivity Tool from GitHub. It's a tool that allows you to decompile the contents of an OpenXML file (like a .xlsx file). Maybe you can use it to go spelunking within the file to find a solution. Also consider adding an openxml tag to your question

Thanks Fly. I will try that out. Currently trying other libraries to see if I can get that author name. Will try OpenXML next.

SOLUTION using epplus. In my case I can assume there will only be one comment on the whole sheet so if you cannot there is more work for you to do. Anyways the worksheet has a ThreadedComment property that will contain the displayName. That displayName is nested inside at worksheet.ThreadedComments.Persons.PersonsXml.InnerXml. The inner xml then needs to be parsed so you can grab the value of displayName. That is where my "John Smith" is. Not the guid.

You should post that as a proper answer - yes, you can answer your own question. Could be potentially helpful and useful to someone else trying to do the same thing !

Just added the answer. Thanks marc_s.

In my case I can assume there will only be one comment on the whole sheet so if you cannot there is more work for you to do. Anyways the worksheet has a ThreadedComment property that will contain the displayName. That displayName is nested inside at worksheet.ThreadedComments.Persons.PersonsXml.InnerXml. The inner xml then needs to be parsed so you can grab the value of displayName. That is where my "John Smith" is. Not the guid.
